# How to add information to Lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox

I want to know how to add information to the side of an image using lightbox.
This is some of my code as an example. The lightbox works perfectly but what I want to achieve is when I click the image the image expands and also displays information about the image to the side of it, all with in the lightbox.

```
<article class="style1">
    <span class="image">
    <a href="images/image1.jpg" data-lightbox="galleryone"><img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </span> 
</article>
```

Comment: could you please show us the code that you've done so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

if you're using fancybox, try to use `title` attribute for `<a>`. it should work

```
<a href="images/image1.jpg" data-lightbox="galleryone"><img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="" title="your information"></a>
```

Comment: I'm using lightbox :) i tried the title attribute but altering was very limited. I wasnt able to alter size of texts e.g. h1, h2, p which is what im trying to do

Comment: "Lightbox" you should be more specific. Can you tell me the exact plugin you're using? Share me the link, so it will be more helpful. Perhaps you could share working example on the question so it will be more understandable

Comment: @Belfastboy95 and could you show me how it looks after using title?